# access all files in a directory

Tags: python, file

I wanted to access all the files in a directory.But I could only able to access the first file in the directory.

How could I access any file present in the directory?

My code:

```
import os
path = r'C:\Python27\aisources'
sfile=raw_input("What is your filename to check? ")
if os.path.exists(sfile):   #-->sfile is user input to check file present / not
     with open(sfile,'r') as f:
         print 'its present'
else:
    print 'not there'
```

The path consists of files like:

```
a1
a2
a3
```

But it only returns present if a1 is raw input.For a1 and a2 it results 'not there' eventhen its present in the path.

Please help!Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: there's no obvious reason this should happen, maybe show us the actual file names and actual input to raw_input

Comment: this is what i tested by creating a new files and folders by giving the above names.

Comment: Do your files have extensions?  You should also include the full path when checking the file names, so ```if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,sfile)):```

Comment: yes i have extentensions like `a1.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually using the full path, try using `os.path.join`:

```
path = 'C:/Python27/aisources/' 
sfile = raw_input("What is your filename to check? ")
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,sfile)):   #-->sfile is user input to check file present / not
     with open(os.path.join(path,sfile),'r') as f:
         print('its present')
else:
    print('not there')
```

`os.path.join(path,sfile)` presumes you are checking the directory `'C:/Python27/aisources/'`  for each file.

You can also use `chdir` to change the directory:

```
path = 'C:/Python27/aisources/' 
os.chdir(path)
sfile=raw_input("What is your filename to check? ")
if os.path.exists(sfile):
     with open(sfile,'r') as f:
         print('its present')
else:
    print('not there')
```